# Search for favorited questions on the Android app

Tags: support, bookmarks, android-app

Some days ago I was reading math.stackexchange on my Android device via the official app when I found a really good answer to a question. I clicked to favorite the question, but now I find that the favorite list does not exist on the app. How can I recover my favorite list there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for `infavorites:mine` (or, more generally, `infavorites:<UID>` to search for questioned favorited by the user with ID `UID`) when viewing the Mathematics site in the app.

(Note that this is a [known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229697) with the Android app.)